# How to bring the cursor to the start of the word which the cursor is currently pointed to?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Usually after I've typed a word like say `Wikipedia`:

> `Typing.. Tying.. Wikipedia[cursor here]`

I want to "select" that word, so basically I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> x 9

Now slowly this gets annoying, so I was wondering

How do we "select" the last typed word without using a mouse? (that does better than the above solution)

Comment: In what program? Different programs use different keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @CarlF in Windows, which will work on *almost* all programs. Something like Ctrl-C Ctrl-V, if you know what I mean..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> will do the trick.

Comment: That's amazing ed !

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Left will work if the cursor is at the *end* of a word, which is not quite what the OP asked (although it may be what he wanted).